# How to suspend a process for a certain period of time?

Tags: shell, process, cron, signals

I have several running processes which is started by a shell, but I don't want them to run during 08:00am - 20:00pm for each day because they are really bandwidth-consuming, so , I have to suspend them during that period of time instead of killing them directly because killing them will cause some problems.So , my work ,is to suspending them at 08:00am and waking them up at 20:00pm every day.Anyone can tell my how to do that ? 
I tried to do this in crontab, I use `kill -19 pid` to suspend them but I don't know how to wake them up by pid number.

Maybe a shell script will be quite appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use word notation for more readability :

```
kill -STOP <PID> # pause
kill -CONT <PID> # continue working
```

Check

```
man 7 signal
```